# haproxy ACLs regex and logical or

Tags: regex, haproxy

If I have URL of the form `/q/a/1234` or `/q/b/456` or `/q/c/987` and `/q/x/abc` or `/q/y/3455`.

I want to route any URLs of the form `/q/[a|b|c]/.*` i.e anything which is meant to the queues a or b or c to one backend, and anything which is meant for `/q/[x|y]/.*`  to a different backend, how would I achieve this?

I attempted:

```
acl use_server_1 path_reg /a|b|c/
use backend server1 if user_server_1

acl use_server_2 path_reg /x|y/
use backend server2 if user_server_2
```

This does not match routes correctly.... Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need a `|` within a character class (unless you want a literal `|` to also be a valid match).

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error. You define your regex as `use_server_1` and `use_server_2`, yet your 'use' statement is attempting a comparison against `useR_server_1` and `useR_server_2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
acl use_server_1 path_reg ^/q/[abc]/?.*$
use backend server1 if use_server_1

acl use_server_2 path_reg ^/q/[xy]/?.*$
use backend server2 if use_server_2
```